# Checkbox Strikeout text when ticked

Tags: c#, fonts, strikethrough

I have been trying to get the text strikeout when it is ticked in a check box. I have been looking on the web for the last two days and finally decided to post here for help.

Basically, I would like to build a to-do list app and when a task is ticked it gets striked through.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What UI Framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try Like This Plan CSS/HTML no JavaScript required.**

```css
.todo-box {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.todo-item {
  padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
  background: gold;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted green;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+label.strikethrough {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  content: "\00a0";
  display: inline-block;
  font: 16px/1em sans-serif;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 .25em 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="todo-box">
  <li>
    <div class="checkbox todo-item">
      <input type="checkbox" name="packersOff" value="1" />
      <label for="packers" class="strikethrough">001 Task Item</label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="checkbox todo-item">
      <input type="checkbox" name="packersOff" value="1" />
      <label for="packers" class="strikethrough">002 Task Item</label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="checkbox todo-item">
      <input type="checkbox" name="packersOff" value="1" />
      <label for="packers" class="strikethrough">003 Task Item</label>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JackRyu/746b8xLj/1/)

Comment: @archtest Accept the answer if it's helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Windows Forms:

1. Open the form in the Windows Forms designer and add a checkbox.
2. Double-click the checkbox in the designer to add a handler.
3. In the handler, add the following code.

(assuming the checkbox is called `checkBox1`):

```
void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    checkBox1.Font = new Font(
        checkBox1.Font,
        checkBox1.Checked ? FontStyle.Strikeout : FontStyle.Regular);
}
```

Note that this does not dispose the old font handle, but code does not normally bother to do that.

Comment: Hi Matthew, thank you looking into this. I have tried similar approach but keep getting this error: "CheckedListBox" does not contain a definition for "Checked" and no accessible extension method "Checked" accpting a first argument of type "CheckedListBox" could be found. What am I missing here? Thanks

Comment: Ah, you're using a `CheckedListBox` rather than a `CheckBox`. They are different controls. Can you confirm that you are using Windows Forms? Or are you using html?

Comment: My bad, apologies! I am using the CheckedListBox with Windows Forms.

Comment: Hi Mathew, would you be able to review this when you get a chance. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @archtest Unfortunately, `CheckedListBox` doesn't support changing the font for each line - you would have to create a custom version of it. [Here's some sample code showing how to do it](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1062442/A-Multi-Color-Multi-Font-CheckedListBox)

Comment: Noted. I will go through that thread and review. Thank you for your assistance, it is highly appreciated!